# How to specify path for images in CSS file?

Tags: angular

How to specify path to images in css styles for component?

My styles are stored in assets directory, but components in others.
When I try to set full path it is so long.

Sample is:

```
background: url(../../assets/img/angularclass-avatar.png)
```

Comment: This seems to be the right way to set the path

Comment: Can I set constant like this: `PATH = ../../assets/img/` and use only  `angularclass-avatar.png`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

```
background: 'url(/assets/img/angularclass-avatar.png);'
```

Comment: Also I can define variable in SASS and just pust it everywhere

Comment: Is there no way to make the relative path work as is?

Comment: @user987949, it depends where the resources are. But the relative path is not the issue

Comment: When I use a relative path in CSS I get a build error:
With this:
ERROR in ./src/styles.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):

Comment: @user987949 Where is /images relative to /app or /src?

Comment: I have
src->app->assets->styles->style.css
and the image is in:
src->app->assets->images->image.png

Comment: @user987949 remove assets from app and put next to it. So you should have /src/assets and /src/app

Comment: That did not help, but I've found the "problem".
I used a styles.css file which was referenced in angular.json.
This file referenced all other styles with @import.
When I add the style with the issue to angular.json, it seems to solve it.